# Getting username after login in visual basic .net

Tags: vb.net, logging

Im new programming using vb.net as a programming language, but, the thing is, I want to put the username after a valid login process using a form login.

Something, like this:

[Logged User after login - VBNET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJjqP.png)

See ya,

Comment: How you would do that depends on how you have implemented user management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like jmcilhinney said, it depends on how you've implemented it.

I, personally, would do something simple... create a class...

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Shared savedusername As String = Nothing
End Class
```

When your login form loads, assuming you have a textbox for the login, you can simply save the variable.

```
Class1.savedusername = textbox1.text
```

and to retrieve the variable, simply call `savedusername`

```
label1.text = class1.savedusername
```

There are many ways to do what you're wanting, and this is only one way, and not the best way either.

Comment: Is needed show the user registered in the database. Maybe obtaining the value using a datareader. Anyway thanks for your comment sir :)